# Asus rog tuf fx504 touchpad stops working for a while and then works again?

Tags: touchpad, laptop, 18.10

I've got this laptop recently and the touchpad didn't work at all with ubuntu. Upgrading to kernel 4.19 solved the problem partly. Now it's working but after 1-2 hours of use the touchpad randomly turns off (cursor wont move) and then works again after 2-3 minutes. The OS itself is responsive I can use alt-tab and I can type stuff. Any ideas how to solve the problem? I really don't want to install windows but this is really annoying.

I'm on Ubuntu 18.10 with kernel: 4.19.0-041900-generic

output of less /proc/bus/input/devices

```
I: Bus=0018 Vendor=04f3 Product=3090 Version=0100
N: Name="ELAN1200:00 04F3:3090 Touchpad"
P: Phys=i2c-ELAN1200:00
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/i2c_designware.0/i2c-1/i2c-ELAN1200:00/0018:04F3:3090.0001/input/input13
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event10 
B: PROP=5
B: EV=1b
B: KEY=e520 10000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=2e0800000000003
B: MSC=20
```

Answer (score 0):

This a pretty common bug, this link should help: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1781879/comments/83

Comment: This may answer the question, but you need to make it elaborate...